# Will PostgreSQL engine optimize this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have two queries like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (status IN (1,2,3) OR status IN (3,4,5)) AND ... AND status IN (2,3)
```

and this one:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND status IN (2,3)
```

These queries are executed in almost same time that makes me think that SQL engine optimizes first query and makes somthing like in second example.

Am I right or wrong? Is there any profit to optimize first query manually to the second one, or I can rely on SQL engine?

Comment: EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) is your best friend. Use this for you queries and check the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL probably does the right thing here as long as the items in your `IN()` clauses are constants.

To verify that, you can run both queries prefixed with [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) and examine the execution plans. Completely understanding execution plans takes some work. But PostgreSQL probably reduces all those `IN()` clauses to a single lookup predicate.